# What will happen? If I use maximum no of primary keys in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If I use more than 10 no of primary keys in oracle, then what will be the impact on this? any storage or performance issue will there or not. Kindly explain.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you going to face this hypothetical situation in practical applications?

Comment: Yes, In my business logic has this kind of situation.

Comment: Well, then, if you need it, do it. Optimize your system later when you actually face any problems. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: This would mean only your primary kry values occupy more tham 100GByte of tablespace - good luck!

Comment: But before do it, I just want a clarification on this issue. So that I raised it.

Comment: How It is going to occupy more tablespace? Can you explain me?

Comment: Was a mistake, forget the 100GByte

Answer (score 0):

Surely it will impact performance.
Primary key is always indexed, so it will speed up DB Read operation (data retrieval) however  it will affect records insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one primary key on a table (by definition). Do you mean that you have one primary key consisting of 10+ columns? If so, you can use a sequence generator to devise a surrogate key, and keep a unique constraint on the 10 columns (so that they cannot be duplicated on insert). Your inserts will still have to check the constraint, of course.

Generally your tables should be designed to avoid this sort of thing by normalizing the table structure.